# apache airflow configuration is empty and dags && plugins missing

Tags: airflow

I have installed apache airflow on Ubuntu 18.4 using this link https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html
now when  i run airflow with

> airflow webserver --port 8080

and the Admin/Configurtion is empty and there is this message:

> "Your Airflow administrator chose not to expose the configuration,
> most likely for security reasons."
> [image]

What i did wrong?
More information that me be helpfull  is that i created an user[airflow] and do all installtion with sudo , so my airflow info is :

```
Paths info                                                                                                                                                               
airflow_home    | /home/airflow/airflow                                                                                                                                  
system_path     | /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin                                                     
python_path     | /usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/python36.zip:/usr/lib/python3.6:/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-pac
                | kages:/home/airflow/airflow/dags:/home/airflow/airflow/config:/home/airflow/airflow/plugins                                                            
airflow_on_path | True                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                         
Config info                                                                                                                                                                   
executor             | LocalExecutor                                                                                                                                          
task_logging_handler | airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler                                                                                                    
sql_alchemy_conn     | postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@localhost:5432/airflow                                                                                           
dags_folder          | /home/airflow/airflow/dags                                                                                                                             
plugins_folder       | /home/airflow/airflow/plugins                                                                                                                          
base_log_folder      | /home/airflow/airflow/logs
```

However these folder does not exists also :/home/airflow/airflow/dags && /home/airflow/airflow/plugins

Comment: could you paste your airflow.cfg file?

Comment: Hi @AnandVidvat , my airflow.cfg has 1014 lines! .Could  i know which parts you are interested  in?

Answer (score 16):

You will probably need to set `expose_config = True` in `airflow.cfg` and restart the web-server.

Comment: what if the airflow is hosted inside of kubenates (AKS), i did change the values.yaml file to have `AIRFLOW__CORE__EXPOSE_CONFIG: "True"`, and then run the helm upgrade to deploy the airflow again `helm upgrade "${_airflow_name}" airflow-stable/airflow  --version 7.16.0 --namespace ${_namespace_airflow} -f values.yaml`, then restarted the web server one more time, but when i log onto the web-server pod, i see the value in airflow.cfg file is still False.

Comment: okay, it turns out it should be `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: "True"`

Answer (score 6):

As [@somuchtolearnandshare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4582240/somuchtolearnandshare) mentioned, it should be `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: "True"`

Answer (score 3):

If You are running airflow inside the docker using the YAML file then please go to the docker-compose.YAML file and add this is a line under the env tag:
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: 'true'

This should fix the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "under the env tag"? You realize there are 6 environment tags in the current Docker Compose file? It would help if you specify which environment tag you're referring to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm deploy airflow with helm chart, but it should help.

First, you need content file values, command (helm chart)

```
helm show values apache-airflow/airflow > values.yaml
```

Find in file values: extraEnv, put the value below and save.

```
extraEnv: |
  - name: AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG
  value: 'TRUE'
```

now, run changes with command below

```
helm upgrade  --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow -n airflow -f values.yaml --debug
```

Comment: The helm chart can also just use `config:   webserver:  expose_config: "True"`

Answer (score 2):

For those running Airflow with docker-compose, you can modify the docker-compose.yaml to include the last line below:

```
version: '3.8'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-airflow-custom}
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that for "Azure bitnami Airflow multi-tier" implementation.

```
expose_config = True
```

in `airflow.cfg` and restart the web-server did the trick